# xcode 10b6 fabric missing or malformed provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, google-fabric, xcode10beta6

Just updated to Xcode 10b6 and when i try to distribute the app through the fabric plugin i got the error "Archive Preparation Error: -3" - The archive's embedded.mobileprovision provisioning is missing or malformed"

No idea how to solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just find myself trying stuff..

1. File -> Workspace settings
2. Change Build system from New Build System (default) to Legacy Build System

Comment: what version of xcode is that? 10.1 has no `file >> workplace settings` menu item

Comment: @DanielLizik is file >> project settings

Answer (score 2):

In xcode 10+ the option to change to legacy build is in `file >> project settings`

[image][image]

Comment: also seems like I have to manually set this everytime I close/open xcode